# Creating a separate table for how much data for each variable is missing [n(%age missing)]

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have been asked by a journal to provide how much of the data in a large Table 1 is complete and how much is missing, in a separate supplementary table.

Ideally like:

| Variable | Group 1 (n = 128) | Group 2 (n=100) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 128 (100%) | 100 (100%) |
| Sex | 64 (50%) | 75 (75%) |

and so on...

Each variable is formatted as n(percentage complete) in the table.

I know about the `missing = "if any"` and have been using that, but I can't find a way even with the modify() commands to make a table with just this info. They don't want `add_n()` style total numbers and missing information in the Table 1 within the manuscript itself.

Is there a relatively straightforward that I am missing and can do this?

Comment: Please include a sample of your data or mock data pasting the output of `dput(data)` into the question or using `dat<-data.frame(var1 = ...., var2 = ...., etc...)` to make a reproducible question.

Answer (score 2):

You can first replace each column with a logical indicating whether the value is missing (i.e. NA), then pass the table to `tbl_summary()` for the missing rates to be tabulated.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

# first make an indicator if a value is missing
trial %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = -trt, .fns = is.na)) %>%
  # then createa summary table tabulating missing data rates
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  modify_caption("Missing Data Counts") %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Drug B**, N = 102 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| age | 7 (7.1%) | 4 (3.9%) |
| marker | 6 (6.1%) | 4 (3.9%) |
| stage | 0 (0%) | 0 (0%) |
| grade | 0 (0%) | 0 (0%) |
| response | 3 (3.1%) | 4 (3.9%) |
| death | 0 (0%) | 0 (0%) |
| ttdeath | 0 (0%) | 0 (0%) |

Missing Data Counts

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this! That's fantastic. Verified and works really well. Is there a way to flip the argument so it shows how many are available (%age available) instead of unavailable. I thought a `!is.na` in ``mutate(across(.cols = -g_lancet, .fns = is.na))`` would do it but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'll want to use `.fns = ~!is.na(.)`

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly. Thanks for being so responsive on here. Another vote for my favourite R package!